# Web RDP not working in 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I am not able to connect to the remote machine from Ubuntu 11.10 machine using Web RDP.

The following  are the details.

```
Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation Java Version: 1.7.0_07
IVE Host: xxx.xxx.com
Run Level:0, read timeout:90000
Applet is signed and trusted
webRDP version: 1.0.8.16, 2011-04-14 10:34
Attempting to obtain the license from the application jar.
Obtained the license from the application jar.
Keyboard: IBM101
```

I have removed the actual host name from the above details

The error message on a pop up window is

```
Application Error
UnsatisfiedLinkError
Unable to load library 'libX11':liblibX11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
This error happens soon after Applet loads.
```

I am supposed to get a WebRDP Screen with logo then a Windows Login screen for the remote machine.

(This is working fine in Linux Mint)

Anyone has experienced this problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to open liblibX11.so file and it doesn't exist.

A tempo crapy bug fix : `you can symlink the libX11.so to liblibX11.so` (find it with the locate tool or anything supplied with this "fordum[b|p]" distrib.

A better way : get the sources and change the filename